# Android Data Message (Binary SMS)

Tags: android, sms, message, binary-data

I am thinking of using SMSManager.sendDataMessage for one of my
applications.  Can anyone let me know:

1. Is the size limit (no. of characters) per data message, same as
   text message?
2. If not, what is the rationale behind that and what is the limit?
3. Which limit does SMSManager.divideMessage uses, text message limit
   or data message limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, they are different.
2. from smpp version 3.4
   ---- snip ----
   6.2
   Maximum Message Length
   Each network variation is limited to some fixed maximum length. This may be 
   further affected by data coding scheme.
   The SMSC, depending on configuration, may reject or truncate messages that 
   exceed the network allowed maximum.
   ---- snip ----

   When you integrate with a telco carier, you should read into their 
   documentation which should mentioned what are the encoding you should use
   and its corresponding length. Then cross check with your implementation.
3. neither. it checks the message encoding and determine the maximum length for
   that message. then it will do substring to the original message and return
   the splitted messages in ArrayList.

   Read here on how the divideMessage called is made.
   http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/telephony/SmsManager.java#SmsManager.divideMessage%28java.lang.String%29
   http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/telephony/SmsMessage.java#SmsMessage.fragmentText%28java.lang.String%29